# SharePoint 2010 workflows doesn't start when an item is Updated by provider hosted App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, provider-hosted-app

I'm working on 2013.

I'm using 2010 workflows for sending emails to external users on item update.

But the items are created  using Provider hosted App by the user name "SharePoint APP" and App is given full control permission.

Scenario's Tried:

1. Tried calling 2010 workflow from 2013 workflow - not working
2. Tried triggering the workflow through code but since we use third party authentication it is merely not possible and also includes lot of work and not a smooth solution.

Comment: It is by default that SharePoint 2010 workflows are not triggered by items created by event receiver/workflow/provider hosted app.when you tried to call 2010 workflow from 2013 workflow, is there an error displaying? What did you mean it didn't work?

Comment: Error displayed is  Internal Status:   Suspended , Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401 {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

Comment: Even group emails cannot be sent using 2013 workflows when updated by SharePoint Apps. is this an limitation for Provider hosted App?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the authorization for the workflow instance. So you can try with activating the feature called "Workflow can use app permissions" under Site Settings --> Site Features.